# Tomcat returns 403 after setting error-page

Tags: spring, tomcat

Ok so I wanted to replace the Tomcat 7 default error page.  Therefore, I set the error-page element in my web.xml for our application.

After doing this I noticed that a number of our integration tests where failing and all 40x statuses were returned as HTTP 403.  For instance, normally one of our tests should return 404 but instead 403 is returned when the error-page is enabled.

Most of our integration tests pass as they are GETs or POSTs.  However, the tests that are failing are all PUTs.  Again these tests work fine when there are no error-page definitions.

Anyone have any ideas?

I tried setting the readonly parameter for the servlet in the init-parameters but that made no difference.

This is a Spring-Mvc 3.0.5 application.

Comment: Can you post the content of your `web.xml` ?

Comment: And, if possible, post the interesting parts of the error-page that you are trying to use.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve that? I'm having the same issue